# Convert an Array objects to an Array of variables within that object

Tags: java, arrays

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
Point[] points = new Point[]{new Point(2, 3), new Point(7,8), new Point(1, 8)};
int[] xCoords  = new int[points.length];

for (int i = 0; i < points.lenght; i++) {
    xCoords[i] = points[i].x;
}
```

So that in the end I would end up with `xCoords` looking like this:

`{2, 7, 8}`

Is it possible to archive this in a more general fashion?

Comment: First of all the result should be {2, 7, 1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
int[] xCoords = Stream.of(points).mapToInt(Point::getX).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it just depends on which of the two options is more efficient, but I guess it just comes down to styling.

Comment: @Busti Both solutions work. It depends on the level of encapsulation :).

Answer (score 7):

In [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you can do

```
int[] xCoords = Stream.of(points).mapToInt(p -> p.x).toArray();
```

Comment: Well, just for having used streams +1 :D

Comment: I KNEW it was possible using lambda functions!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using a 2D array, e.g:

```
int[][] coordinates = new int[5][];
for(int i=0 ; i < points.size() ; i++){
    coordinates[i] = new int[]{points.get(i).getX(), points.get(i).getY()};
}
```